# Is stopImmediatePropagation() supposed to stop subsequent events derived from a single action?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When clicking on an element to give it focus, the focus event, then the click event, fire. I should be able to stop propagation in the focus event and stop the click handler from running. Right?

But, none of `stopImmediatePropagation`, `preventDefault`, `stopPropagation`, or `return false;` stops the click handler from firing.

Simplified code:

```
eComponentFocus = function(e,eventThis){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();   
   console.log(e.isImmediatePropagationStopped()); // true
   console.log('focus');
   return false;
}


eComponentClick = function(e,eventThis){
   console.log('eComponentClick');
}

var base=this;
$Component.on('focus',function(e){base.eComponentFocus(e,this);});
$Component.on('click',function(e){base.eComponentClick(e,this);});
```

Console, when `$Component`, a `div`, is clicked:

```
true
focus
eComponentClick
```

Is stopImmediatePropagation() supposed to stop subsequent events derived from a single user action?

Update:

Here's a fiddle with the problem. Clicking the div fires focus then click, even though the focus event tries to prevent propagation. http://jsfiddle.net/c99dk/

Comment: are you sure the effect you are seeing is not because of mousedown or mouseup events?

Comment: I added `console.log('eventname');` to all event handlers- Only the focus and click events are being fired when I click the element.

Comment: are you in a touch device or a regular browser? if is a regular browser there should be a mousedown and mouseupevent firing before the click event

Comment: I've added a fiddle with the problem. Its FF24 on the desktop. I don't have any handlers registered for `mousedown` or `mouseup` on this element.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think `stopImmediatePropagation` only stops further events of the same event type resulting from the same user action. If you add a second `focus` handler, it will be canceled by the first.

Comment: @apsillers: That's the question I'm hoping to get an answer to.

Comment: here, there is an example on how you should  prevent focus
http://jsfiddle.net/d65yan/c99dk/1/.
docus happens anter mousedown if the default action is not prevented